# Cannot register modules with Jackson ObjectMapper class

Tags: java, eclipse, jackson

I want to register **Jdk8Module**, **JavaTimeModule**, **GuavaModule** and **JsonOrgModule** modules using Jackson **ObjectMapper** class. I dit it as follows:

```
ObjectMapper objectmapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModules(new AfterburnerModule(), 
                    new Jdk8Module(), new JavaTimeModule(), new GuavaModule(),
                    new JsonOrgModule());
```

But I've got the following error:

> The method registerModules(Module...) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (AfterburnerModule, Jdk8Module, JavaTimeModule, GuavaModule, JsonOrgModule)

Answer (score 0):

For Jackson 1.x, import both `ObjectMapper` and `Module` from `org.codehaus.jackson.map`.

For Jackson 2.x, import both `ObjectMapper` and `Module` from `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind`.

Comment: I am using Jackson Databind 2.9.5 and I have already imported ObjectMapper class from com.fasterxml.jackson.databind and the error is always persisting.

Comment: @MChaker Try to import the modules individually. Do you face errors in all of them? Do all modules you want to register extend `Module` from `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind`?

Comment: I have verified now and the problem is caused by AfterburnerModule. Something really strange! everything goes fine with the other modules.

Comment: `The method registerModule(Module) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (AfterburnerModule)`

Comment: And for the other modules, everything works fine. `ObjectMapper objectmapper = new ObjectMapper()
    .registerModules( new Jdk8Module(), new JavaTimeModule(), new GuavaModule(),
      new JsonOrgModule());`

Comment: @MChaker Where did you get `AfterburnerModule` from? Which package? Which dependency?

Comment: Here is the package `com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.AfterburnerModule`